# How to add hyphen or other valid character in Telligent Blog's Web Addresses and display in Sitecore

Tags: url-rewriting, sitecore, telligent

I have setup two blogs in the Telligent Community site with few posts in them and I have changed the Web Address for them as shown below with examples of Actual and Expected Url in the **sitecore side** site,

1. Sample WebBlog

   Telligent Blog Web Address setting: `Sample-WebBlog`

   Sitecore Actual Url: `http://www.site.com/Community/2/b/sample_2D00_weblog`

   Sitecore Expected Url: `**http://www.site.com/Community/Administrators/b/sample-weblog**`

   Telligent Side Url: `http://localhost/tcdemo/administrators/b/sample-webblog/default.aspx`
2. Sitecore Demo Blog

   Telligent Blog Web Address setting: `Sitecore-Demo-Blog`

   Sitecore Actual Url: `http://www.site.com/Community/1/b/sitecore_2D00_demo_2D00_blog`

   Sitecore Expected Url: `http://www.site.com/Community/Administrators/b/sitecore-demo-blog`

   Telligent Side Url: `http://localhost/tcdemo/administrators/b/sitecore-demo-blog/default.aspx`

So as seen the Url changes the hypen `-` to `_2D00` while in Sitecore and in Telligent it is completely different.

1. So how to add hyphen or other valid url character in the Telligent Blog's Web Addresses (displayed in Sitecore) ?
2. Also How to display the group name instead of Group ID in the url (also check the screenshot from Telligent widget below) ?

**Telligent widget - Sitecore debug widget**

[image: Telligent widget - Sitecore debug widget]

**Telligent widget - Blog widget**

[image: Telligent widget - Blog widget]

Comment: Can I download that blog widget and the rest of the module somewhere or it's required to buy it first? I don't know the module, but if I have the binaries I can take a look at it.

Comment: The widgets are part of the Sitecore Social Kit for Telligent integration, available from Sitecore SDN (Sitecore Partners have access to download the Social Starter Kit from SDN).

Comment: Also [here](http://telligent.com/community/partner/sitecore_partners/f/1728/t/1073625.aspx) is reply from telligent support on the issue.

Comment: Was hoping to find some custom LinkProvider in that code, but that's not it. Can't see that support case btw, it's protected with a login.